# Call Web Service Deployed on Openshift

Tags: java, php, web-services, openshift

I try to call my web service using php on web service that deployed on my OpenShift account

and I got an error

> "SoapFault exception: [S:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in..."

I already try different method to call but it still cant call it

Try the same web service deployed on localhost and it can and work perfectly

The error retrieved when I try to try catch
$SOAPClient = new SoapClient(" web service url here ');
it returns null

PHP Code

```
//=============================== Try the web Service Connection =====================================
try {
    $SOAPClient = new SoapClient("http://cloudmarket-yatohime.rhcloud.com/SCMWebServices/CreateMarketWebService?wsdl");
    $result = $SOAPClient->launchSCM();
    if (!$result) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "CreateMarketWebService error";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = $e;
}
//======================================================================================================
```

Error

> SoapFault exception: [S:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in
> /home/yatohime/smartcloudmarket.com/processes/bid.php:52 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/yatohime/smartcloudmarket.com/processes/bid.php(52): SoapClient->__call('sendTraderSubmi...', Array) #1
>
> /home/yatohime/smartcloudmarket.com/processes/bid.php(52):
> SoapClient->sendTraderSubmission(Array) #2 {main}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post your code so that we can help you http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: added the code , thanks